# Rails 3 Nested resource routes inherits parent constraints, how to avoid it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, constraints, nested-resources

It you define constraint on "id" in parent resource:

```
resources :foo, constraints: { :id => /CONST/ } do
  resources :bar
end
```

The nested resource will inherits that constraint for its own id, thus the generated routes will be like:

```
/foo/:foo_id/bar/:id/edit(.:format)
{:id=>/CONST/, :foo_id=>/CONST/, :action=>"edit", :controller=>"bar"}
```

So, I don't want the "id" parameter of Bar resource to be that restricted.

Currently, I've just map the routes I want manually, one by one, but I am really want to generate it by resources helper. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

How about :

```
resources :foo, constraints: { :id => /CONST/ }
resources :foo, constraints: { :foo_id => /CONST/ } do
  resources :bar
end
```

Comment: Maybe it will work, but I don't like to repeat the line "resources :foo"

Comment: This is highly unfortunate, but it worked for me... I also applied `only: []` to the second definition to make it clear which `resources` call was routing what.